# Best Practice to use flavors in app

Tags: android, android-flavors

I know that I can check for flavors like:

```
  if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("someFlavor")) {
    //do some thing...
}
```

But this deserve very much conditions to check for every step.

What is the best practice to check for flavor?

Comment: What do you mean by "deserve very much conditions to check for every step"? Bear in mind that [you can have separate Java code, resources, etc. for each flavor](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#sourceset-build).

Comment: @CommonsWare I mean, should be there simpler way?  - because this conditions will force me to have a view for each flavor, and custom code for every flavor.

Comment: "should be there simpler way?" -- a "simpler way" of doing what? "because this conditions will force me to have a view for each flavor, and custom code for every flavor" -- no, *you* decided to have a view for each flavor and custom code for every flavor. There is nothing intrinsic with product flavors that requires different layouts or Java code. Those are *options*, and you may wish to use them. Using product flavors at all is an option. We do not know why you are trying to use product flavors or what you hope to gain from them.

Answer (score 2):

You can also have different java files for your different flavors. It depends on your needs and situation.